# Filter out future dates in SQL (WinSQL)

Tags: sql, date

I have a query in winSQL as such:

```
select CALENDAR as CALENDAR,
       HD_FLAG as HD_FLAG,
       counts as COUNTS,
       CAP_location as AREA,
where CALENDAR >= 20150101
group by 1,2,3,4
```

However, there are future data values that I want to filter out. Is there a function or another where clause that I can add that filters out dates past today?

Comment: `AND CALENDAR <= GETDATE()` WinSQL means SQL Server, right?

Comment: Perfect, thanks shawnt00

Answer (score 0):

Use the WINSQL `now()` function so:

```
 select CALENDAR as CALENDAR,
 HD_FLAG as HD_FLAG,
 counts as COUNTS,
 CAP_location as AREA,
 where CALENDAR >= now()
 group by 1,2,3,4
```

Comment: so you can filter "where CALENDAR BETWEEN 20150101 AND now()"